My Images hosted on cdn, Indexed as a separate entity. How to avoid this?
I want to let google index images with root domain, not separate entity, that is hosted on separate cdn url.
we tried robots.txt file with disallow rule on cdn s3, but this removes images from embedded sites results also.
